# My program relies on hashes to identify files, some are repeated. How can I work around this?

Tags: database, hash, match

sorry for the messy title but I can't come up with something that really describes what's happening here. So I'm making a program that fetches .cue files for Playstation 1 roms. To do this, the program creates a SHA-1 hash of the file and checks it in a database. The database can be found in the "psx.hash" file in [this](https://github.com/tralph3/Cue-Maker) repo. This has been working fine but I suddenly stumbled upon a very very nasty problem. There's plenty of files that have the same hash, because they are essentially the same file.

Let me break down the problem a bit. PSX roms are essentially cd files, and they can come in tracks. These tracks usually contain audio, and the .cue file is used to tell the emulator where each audio track is located [in the disc file]. So what I do is to identify each and every track file (based on their SHA-1 hash), see if they match the database, and then construct a link based on their name (minus the track text) to get to the original cue file. Then I read the text and add it to the cue, simple as that. Well, apparently many games use the same track for some reason? Exactly 175 of them
[image]

So... what can I do to difentiate them? This leads to the problem that I fetch the wrong cue file whenever this hash comes into play. This is the hash by the way: "d9f92af296360772e62caa4cb276de3fa74f5538". I tried other algorithms to see if it was just an extremely unlikely coincidence, but nope, all gave the same results. SHA-256 gave the same result, CRC gave the same result, MD5 gave the same result (by the same result I mean the same between files, of course the results of different algorithms for the same file will be different).
So I don't know what to do. This is a giant bug in my program that I have no idea on how to fix, any insight is welcome. I'm afraid I explained myself poorly, if so, I apologize, but I have a hard time seeing where I may not be clear enough, so if you have any doubts please, do ask.

It's worth noting that the database was not constructed by myself, but by redump.org, also, here's the code I'm using to retrieve the hashes of the files:

```
def getSha1(file):
    hashSha1 = hashlib.sha1()
    with open(file, "rb") as f:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(4096), b""):
            hashSha1.update(chunk)
    return hashSha1.hexdigest()
```

Comment: If they are, as you say, essentially the same file, does it matter which of them you actually store and use for all 175? If I understand it correctly, the first time you saw that file you hashed it, didn't find it, and added it. The next time, for another title, that you saw the same file contents, you again hashed it, found it, and reused it. Does that matter? It should be the same contents.

Comment: Yes it matters. I'm saying that they're the same file because they have the same hash and file size, but even if they are, games can store it in different places on the disc, so I require to identify to which game this particular instance belongs to to create a correct cue file. What the file is doesn't matter as much as where the file is, if I explain correctly, and that varies by game.

Comment: Then you either need to have a separate table for that information, linked to the actual game, and just use the hash system as a deduplication method, or you will have to avoid this deduplication and store each file separately with the required information about where they're located, even if they have the same hash.

Comment: If "where it is" matters then that's probably what you should be hashing, or at least including in the hash.

Comment: Hmm I don't think I can implement that honestly. I mean "where it is" as in, on the disc, not on the hard drive but the physical CD-ROM. Of course these files are ripped from there, but the cue is made to tell the program where to look for them [on the CD-ROM]. So, I grab an example. "Resident Evil (Track 2)" has the hash "1bdjasu8372", then I match that hash on the database, remove the "Track 2" part of the name, fetch the cue from the link and write it into a local cue file. If another game has a file with the same hash, you can see where the problem arises, I'd get another cue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct solution would be to construct the hash file in such a way that I can differentiate between track files for each game, but I ended up doing the following:

1. Sort the list of Tracks to have them ordered.
2. Get the first track file and retrieve the hash (this one will always be unique since it contains the game)
3. For every next track file that isn't `Track 1`, assume it belongs to the game before it. So if the next file is `Track 2`, assume it belongs to the previous file that had `Track 1`.

This nicely avoids the issue, although it's circumventing the bigger problem of not having properly formatted data.